# iOS Trouble applying animation to UISearchBar

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar

I'm doing a lot of customization to a couple search bars that are side by side in the same view.  Below is an animation block that has the search bar on the left over take the width of the screen when it is selected.  The end result is exactly what I want, but for some reason there is no animation when the UIView animateWithDuration is called.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
UISearchBar *tempSearchBar = (UISearchBar *) searchBar;

if (tempSearchBar.tag == 1) {
    self.customSearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 185, 44);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.customSearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
                         self.customLocationBar.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 0, 44);
                         self.customLocationBar.hidden = YES;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         self.customSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
                     }];
    self.customSearchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!